# Placing one image over another image in android

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have a imageButton in android which user clicks. Then after his click I want t0 show a tick or a cross image on the toip of it.
How is it possible?

```
            <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/rhino" android:layout_marginRight="20dp"></ImageButton>
```

Comment: I think you have to make two images for that one with tick image and another one is without tick image . First you have to set the without tick image and after click on it you have to change image of ImageButton (Tick Image).

Comment: There is no way to set a transparent image on the top of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put your ImageButton and the tick image in a FrameLayout and make the visbility of the Tick image "Invisible" . So when you click on the ImageButton then change the state of Tick Image to Visible.

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to your [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) and then use one of its setImage methods, such as [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29).

Comment: but that will replace the image, isn'it? I want to put this tick image over it.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I missed the part about putting a tick or cross over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using ImageView. Use **ImageView**

```
testimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);



testimage.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

write the logic to set both type of image to imageview in onclick event

```
public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            System.out.println("..set image button..");

            Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
            layers[0] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_call);
            layers[1] = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_unfocus);
            System.out.println(layers[1]+"...Drawable..."+layers[0]);
            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
            testimage.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);

        }
    };
```

Thanks
Deepak